# Using @Pattern with conditions

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

I want to use `@Pattern` with a condition. I mean in one conditions it should execute one regexp and in other condition it should execute other regexp.

This variable should execute this regexp in **profile** `"dev"`

`@Pattern(regexp = TEMPORARY_STORE_VALIDATION, message = INVALID_STORE_NUMBER)
    private String clubNumber;`

and should execute this in case of **profile** `"qa"`

`@Pattern(regexp = STORE_NUMBER_VALIDATION, message = INVALID_STORE_NUMBER)
    private String clubNumber;`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let spring boot take care of your validators and annotate the beans you create with the right profile?

Comment: I think this is problem of profiling.. you need to implement Sprint-boot Profiling like `dev` , `qa` and `prod` etc..

Now put your regex expression as key-value pair in `application-env.properties`. and your regex expression will be loaded into app as per your profile is enabled.

Now, initialize Your static variable which will be either `STORE_NUMBER_VALIDATION` or `TEMPORARY_STORE_VALIDATION` (choose any one) and now, put your regex accordingly.. Hope this concept works.. (Not sure but i think)..

Comment: @VikrantKashyap: It will not work. I have tried doing this but regexp expects a final string.